# Not showing error message in form(jsp)

Tags: spring, forms, jsp, spring-mvc, controller

I have a problem with showing error message in my form(jsp form).
I create a validator, and want to see errors (if exists) in my form, but the errors not showing, what's problem?

**Part of form**

```
<form:form method="POST" action="/regStoreSuccessful" commandName="storeForm">
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><form:label path="name">Store name</form:label></td>
    <td><form:input path="name" /></td>
    <td><form:errors path="name" cssclass="error"/></td>
  </tr>
```

**Validator**

```
public class StoreValidator implements Validator {

@Override
public boolean supports(Class<?> clazz) {
    return Store.class.equals(clazz);
}

@Override
public void validate(Object target, Errors errors) {
    ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmptyOrWhitespace(errors, "name", "name.empty", "Name field is empty");
}
```

}

**Controller**

```
@Autowired
private StoreValidator storeValidator;

@InitBinder
protected void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
    binder.setValidator(storeValidator);
}

//get method
@RequestMapping(value = "/regStore", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView addStore() throws SQLException {
    ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("Store/regStore", "storeForm", new Store());
}

//post method
@RequestMapping(value = "/regStoreSuccessful", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView addStorePost(@Valid @ModelAttribute("storeForm") Store storeForm, BindingResult bindingResult, Principal principal) throws SQLException {
    ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("redirect:body");

    if(bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
        modelAndView.addObject("errors", bindingResult.getAllErrors());
        return new ModelAndView("redirect:regStore");
    }

    storeService.addStore(storeForm);
    return modelAndView;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The model attributes won't be available after redirect, you should use `RedirectAttributes redirectAttrs` and store errors as flash attributes, that way attributes will be available after the redirect and removed immediately after used, so change your method to

```
//post method
@RequestMapping(value = "/regStoreSuccessful", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView addStorePost(@Valid @ModelAttribute("storeForm") Store storeForm, BindingResult bindingResult, Principal principal, , RedirectAttributes redirectAttrs) throws SQLException {
    ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("redirect:body");

    if(bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
        redirectAttrs.addFlashAttribute("errors", bindingResult.getAllErrors());
        return new ModelAndView("redirect:regStore");
    }

    storeService.addStore(storeForm);
    return modelAndView;
}
```

Comment: It works, thank you). I have one question, how I can do check valid   fields without redirect?

Comment: np, what concerns your question, you can simply return ModelAndView holding the view of the page containing the form, so without using the prefix "redirect:"